# Durable Subscriber on Weblogic. How it work?

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I want to understand a thing: When a durable subscriber is activated on a topic, in add on this topic there is another subscriber (mdb). Is possible that the durable subscriber take the messages and don't provide it to the MDB?

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

When a message is sent to a topic, by intent there's a separation between the publisher and the consumers.

Although there are ways you can create transactional delivery around sending to all consumers, there's no way a consumer can take a message and prevent other consumers from receiving a message as well.